# JavaFx 8 Gives Error with Netbeans Dev Build

Tags: netbeans, javafx, netbeans-7, java-8, javafx-8

I downloaded the netbeans dev build and trying to setup my project with JavaFx with JDK 8

First of all the JavaFx tab is missing in the flatforms dialog in netbeans when I choose the JDK 8 folder. More over when I created a new JavaFx project the project properties->libraries I don't see the 4 jar files what it used to be , I only see an environment variable. Now while running the project it says you need a newer version of JDK. When I add the lib/ext/jfxrt.jar manually then only it works

Is it expected ?

Comment: If you will not receive an answer on the issue, I would recommend to file an issue on Netbeans, in Netbeans bug tracker (it is on netbeans.org site). Possibly, you will get the answer there. But it looks like an issue. And if you will get the answer there, could you please post it here, and a link on it too.